# Spring security custom login redirection conflict

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have created a custom login form using spring security some point of time it working as perfect but some times after login URL is redirecting to css or images or js folders. After i  hit refresh it working fine, i dont know what is wrong with my spring security.

Custom login page

```
<form:form class="form-vertical login-form"   action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <h3 class="form-title">Login to your account</h3>
        <input  type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="j_username"/>
        <input  type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="j_password"/>

        <font color="red">
           <span>${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}</span>
        </font>

    </form:form>
```

Security context xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- We will be defining all security related configurations in this file -->
     <http pattern="/" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> <!-- this means all URL in this app will be checked if user is authenticated -->
        <!-- We will just use the built-in form login page in Spring -->
        <form-login login-page="/" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"  default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/> <!-- the logout url we will use in JSP -->
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <!-- Normally, in this part, you will declare the source of your users
                 But for simplicity, we will hard-code the users. This is very useful while testing setup -->
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="Admin, User"/>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="User"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Login Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String loginForm()
{
    return "login";
}
```

Web xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>YESKAY</display-name>

  <!-- Spring security -->
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Define a filter to enable Spring Security, be sure to use the suggested name 'springSecurityFilterChain' -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


 <!--   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>-->
</web-app>
```

Successful login url

```
http://localhost:8080/PROJECT/home
```

Some times redirect to below url or something else

```
http://localhost:8080/PROJECT/resources/assets/plugins/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.0
```

My folder Structure

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to omit requests for your static resources path from Spring Security's filters, otherwise it can get confused about what the actual request was that triggered a login (since the browser will also send requests for the page resources such as images).

Adding something like

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

to the top of your configuration should do it.

Comment: Is it possible to create another custom login form for the same project? I am using spring 3.0

Comment: Yes. If you search the site for "[spring-security] custom login" you will find a lot of discussions.